# How can I add a hot-key to readline for zsh or bash that takes fills in the 2nd parameter to copy but with .bak?

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, readline

I'd like to make a hot-key for this task I sometimes need to perform:

```bsh
%> cp file.txt.1 file.txt.1.bak
```

Where I've repeated the file name but with a .bak on the end.  I'd like to instead just type:

```bsh
%> cp file.txt.1
```

Hit the quick key and have it add the file name with a .bak extension.  Which would turn the second code snippet into the first.

Is this possible?  And if so how can I have the readline add this second parameter?  (I think it's readline I'd have to program here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, in either bash or zsh, you can enter the command as

```
cp file.txt.1{,.bak}
```

This is [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).

For cases where brace expansion isn't convenient because you want to do more editing on the second argument, in zsh, there's a command [`copy-prev-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-copy_002dprev_002dword) which is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ out of the box. It inserts a copy of the word immediately preceding the cursor. Make sure to type a space before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+. You may prefer to bind [`copy-prev-shell-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-copy_002dprev_002dshell_002dword) which is generally more useful.

```
bindkey '^[^_' copy-prev-shell-word
```

In either bash or zsh, to replicate the last word on the command line, starting from the end of the line, make sure the line ends with a space and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. This cuts and paste the last word plus the trailing space twice. Alternatively, if the line does not end with a space, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. This only works if the last argument doesn't contain whitespace; if it does you need to go back a bit further. You can replace <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> if that works on your setup.

Comment: Thanks, this got me very close.  For whatever reason my `copy-prev-shell-word` is bound to `^[m` instead of `^[^_`, but that will work.